# Angular - Accessing Data Elements in Ngrx Store

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, ngrx, ngrx-store

Right now I have access to the state data, but I can only extract specific data members within the state via async. I'm an Angular and Ngrx beginner (though I have used React/Redux a bit), and was hoping someone could point out what may be an obvious solution. I've researched the problem and have seen people using selectors for certain data elements in the state as a possible solution. However, since I already have the state in the component class I feel like there's probably a simple one-liner to access the data, and my ES6/front-end naivety is precluding usage. There are two comments in the component class prepended with '//**' where I have been trying to access the data.

TL;DR: I can access the data elements I want from my Ngrx store in the component HTML using async, but I don't know how to access the same data elements in the component's class.

**Component class:**

```
interface AppState{
  view: Object
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {
  view: Observable<Object>
  //**I want to be able to have a reference to the viewId and viewData in this class
  //**so I can dispatch an action using those data fields

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>){
    this.view = store.select('view');
    }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**Component HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="view | async as v" style="color:black">{{v.viewId}}</div>
```

**Reducer:**

```
import { ActionReducer, Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as viewIds from './view.ids';
import * as actionTypes from './view.actions';

const defaultState = {
    viewId: viewIds.DEFAULT,
    viewData: {}
}

const newState = (state, newData) => {
    return Object.assign({}, state, newData)
}

export function viewReducer(state: Object = defaultState, action: Action) {
    const data = action.payload;
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.UPDATE_VIEW:
            return newState(state, { viewId: data.viewId, viewData: data.viewData })

        case actionTypes.DO_NOTHING:
            console.log("Do nothing!")
            return state;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can subscribe to your store and get data out of it, but don't forget to unsubscribe when the component is destroyed. Async does that in the background, here are two ways to retrieve data from the store. You can get a better example from the ngrx platform-master at [github's ngrx example app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/example-app)

```
 this.store.select(fromCore.getView).take(1)
  .subscribe(view=> {
    this.viewData= view;
  });

 ///////meth two ///////////
 this.view$ = store.store.select(fromCore.getView);
 this.view$.map(view=> {
     this.viewData= view;
 }).take(1);
```

Comment: calling take(1) will unsubscribe but you can also unsubscribe by calling this.view$.unsubscribe() when you need it (on components usually you do it onDestroy).